# Android studio ,How to fix the gradle error?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After updating android studio 2.1 preview 1, I got a `gradle` error and my project doesn't gets sync after creating a blank project.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 : Create a new workspace.
Step 2 : Place your project in that workspace.
Step 3 : IMPORT your project from new Workspace.

Comment: I hope it's work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I will work it out